# Nested if-conditions vs multiple separated if-conditions with return statement in each one

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, coding-style, conditional-statements

What is the most professional code-style in the below two functions ?

And what if the function become more complex & larger such as to have 20 checks ?

Note: i need to do some stuff after each check, so i can't concatenate all in one if-statement like:

if (vehicle.isBus) && (vehicle.numberOfWheels == 6) && (vehicle.motorVersion == 2019)

```
//first alternative
public bool validate(Vehicle vehicle)
{
    if(vehicle.isBus)
    {
        //do some stuff here related to vehicle.isBus
        if (vehicle.numberOfWheels == 6)
        {
            //do some stuff here related to vehicle.numberOfWheels
            if (vehicle.motorVersion == 2019)
            {
                //do some stuff here related to vehicle.motorVersion
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//second alternative
public bool validate(Vehicle vehicle)
{
    if (!vehicle.isBus)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //do some stuff here related to vehicle.isBus

    if (vehicle.numberOfWheels != 6)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //do some stuff here related to vehicle.numberOfWheels

    if (vehicle.motorVersion != 2019)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //do some stuff here related to vehicle.motorVersion

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Definitely the second one. The first one has too much nesting.

Comment: I think that the first one is preferable because it is extendable. The second one is nice until you need to check also for `vehicle.isMinivan`, and then major refactoring is needed.

Comment: What is "do some stuff?" Is the method validating the vehicle or modifying it? If it's doing both then that's a little bit confusing. But the answer to that might indicate something about how to simplify the code.

Answer (score 2):

One golden rule I follow is to **Avoid Nesting** as much as I can.

Use the one that makes the code more readable and understandable. For just two conditions, the first way is more logical and readable. It might not be the case anymore with 5 or 6 conditions linked with &&, || and !.

So when the number of checks are 5+ then you should prefer **second alternative.**

**Note :** Multiple ifs without each calling return implies that 2 or more ifs could be true.

Answer (score 1):

The second example should require less cognitive overhead while reading the code.

In the first example, you need to keep a mental "stack" of the program state. In the second example, you just need to keep a list of things that you already know to be true.

The second example is also less likely to be confounded by a misplaced brace; in fact it doesn't require any braces at all in this example.